# How to define global variable for a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is my javascript code, the event is onkeyup for many row of table !

```
function product(id)
    {
        $('#customers2').find('tr').click( function(){
            var clicked = this;
        });
            var row = $(clicked).find('#tempnow').val();
            if (row == "noncheck"){
                $(clicked).find('#ett').val("");
                $(clicked).find('#ett').prop("disabled", true);
            }
            else{
                $(clicked).find('#ett').prop("disabled", false);
                $.ajax({
                    url:baseurl+"/getinform/", 
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {masp : id},
                    success:function(data) {      
                        var thue = data['pcs_cl_pd_thue'];
                        $(clicked).find('#tyu').css("color", "red");
                        $(clicked).find('#tyu').val(thue);              
                    }
                }); 
            }

    }
```

When i use firebug, variable clicked is not defined ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope

Answer (score 1):

```
var clicked; // Define it outside

$('#customers2').find('tr').click( function(){
    clicked = this; // Give it a value on click, from inside a function
    next() // Now it has a value, call another function that'll do something with it
});

function next(){
     $(clicked).find('#ett') // It works!
}
```